# Need help on this Limit of an Integral

Tags: real-analysis

Can you help me show the following statement?
If $\displaystyle{F(t) = \int_{t^2}^{t} \frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}}~dx}$, then $F(t) \to \infty$ as $t \to 0^+$. I am really not sure how to argue this.

Comment: $\cos x \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$.

Comment: Hint: $\cos x \geq 1 - \frac{x^2}{2}$ for all $x$ or $\cos x \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for small enough $x$

Answer (score 0):

> $$F(t) = \int_{t^2}^{t} \frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}}~dx\to\infty\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{as }t\to0^+$$

For small $0\leq t\leq1$, we should have a nonnegative evaluation of $F(t)$, for the integrand when graphed is above the $x$-axis. Furthermore, the integrand has an asymptote at $x=0$:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}}=\infty$$
Now you should be able to formalize this.

Comment: Your analysis is not enough to conclude $F(t)\to+\infty$. There is a tug of war between growing integrand and shrinking domain of integration, and a well-designed bounds can lead to a non-trivial answer. For example, we can check that $$\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{t^2}^{t^2+t^3}\frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x=1.$$

Comment: I am speechless. How is this integral even thought of, as $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_{t^3}^{t^3+t^4}\frac{\cos x}{x^{3/2}}dx\$$ seems to approach infinity too? I do not have a formal education in calculus yet, but I would like to see a proof for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do Taylor-expansion on the numerator, you get:

$$\int\frac{cos(x)}{x^\frac{3}{2}}dx \geq \int \frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^\frac{3}{2}}dx$$

Then you must solve the integral, and evaluate the limit. Since the integral to the right of the inequality is smaller, but goes to infinity, your actual integral also goes to infinity. Since it is greater.

I hope this helps, and that this answer is acceptable to the standards of this forum. :)